# How to understand characters

Tags: number-theory

I am wondering where I can learn the material to understand questions like this, and the symbols.

[image]

Thank you to all

Comment: What part of the question don't you understand?

Comment: @anomaly My mistake, I would just like to know where I could learn this type of material

Comment: You mean how to write these things or about this specific topic?

Comment: @Dovah-king This specific topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look like [Dirichlet characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character), which are used in the proof of [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) on primes in arithmetic progressions (and [Prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions)-like extensions of it). Check any book or notes on Analytic Number theory. Davenport's multiplicative number theory opens with a chapter on this. There's notes by [Hildebrand](http://staff.polito.it/danilo.bazzanella/PhD_files/Introduction%20to%20ANT.pdf) online that end with a chapter on this. It is also a special case of characters in the [representation theory of finite groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups#Character_theory) of which there are also many introductory references.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why on the Wikipedia page that you linked, on example four, it says a character may not be a group homomorphism. I thought they were defined as such?

Comment: @PersonaA They're usually defined as traces of the representation matrices. (Maybe you're thinking of a representation, which is defined as a homomorphism.)

Comment: @PersonaA or maybe it's to do with the fact that they're the same thing for a one-dimensional representation, and every irreducible representation of an abelian group is one-dimensional (thus for Dirichlet characters)

Comment: Yes good points, I think it is the second case